# Running a command when Powershell enters a new directory

Tags: powershell

I want to automatically run a command whenever Powershell enters a new directory (my key interest is in checking if I am in a Python virtualenv and activating it if I am, but I can imagine other uses - I'm trying to port https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv to Powershell).

How can I do this? So far, I've thought of a couple of options, but they aren't ideal:

1. Add a check in my prompt function to see if the directory has changed. My biggest problem with this is that it will add overhead to my prompt (which I'd rather avoid) and it'll do a lot of unnecessary checks as I don't change directory that often.
2. Override the `Set-Location` cmdlet. I think this is what PSCX does, but it only affects the `cd` alias. So it'd probably be incomplete (there's also `Push-Location`, as well as any other user-defined stuff). Also, it wouldn't work for the directory Powershell starts up in (as that's set by the shortcut, not by a `Set-Location` command).
3. I was hoping there was an engine event or something similar for this, but I can't see one. Also, event handlers run as background tasks which might not work (I haven't tested this).

Are there any better options that I've missed? Or does anyone have any advice on how to implement this efficiently?

Comment: I would say that the overhead of an if statement with a simple comparison, to see if the directory has changed or not, would likely be negigible. No matter which approach you'd solve it with you'd still have to check if it is a virtualenv and activate it, so the only thing that differs between any solution which is alerted only on directory change and handling the actual prompt write, to check if the directory has changed, is that last check. Therefore I would suggest using option number 1.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I'll try that. It's probably about time I wrote a module to manage all the bits in my prompt function - it's getting quite complicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I'm aware of is to modify the prompt function.  That's how posh-git works, though it makes sense for posh-git because they do actually change the prompt when you change to a repo.

You might try creating proxy functions for Set-Location and Push-Location, but those won't work in general because any function could change directories by calling an API instead of using those commands, similar to how PSCX does it (with a cmdlet Set-LocationEx.)

Comment: Thanks, yes I think the prompt function is the best option.

Comment: @PaulMoore, did you make a solution we could joyously borrow?

Comment: @zelusp: I just put one up at [PSGallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ps-autoenv/) if you're still looking.

Answer (score 0):

I would go that way : override the cd alias 
a poor example could be

```
function set-env{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline = $true)] $path
        )

    set-location $path
    # stupid test
    if ($path -match "temp"){
        echo "warning this is a temporary dir"
    }
}

Remove-Item -path alias:cd -ea silentlycontinue  
new-item -Path alias:cd -Value set-env |out-null


cd c:\temp\
```

Comment: It'd have to be more complex than that. A `cd` alias wouldn't catch `Set-Location` or `Push-Location` or `Pop-Location`... (you get the idea). And it would also remove the `cd` alias that PSCX adds for its own extension. So I'm not sure it's a good enough solution :-(